# Don't understand why values retrieved from matrix don't converge as expected

Tags: python, matrix

I'm currently doing a work for college where I'm programing a **F**inite **V**olume **M**ethod in Python to solve a heat transfer problem.

I need to import some data from a matrix with values for the characteristics from the materials. When I was using constant characteristics, so without calling from the matrices, it was doing cool and converging through the iterations, even if it was to a wrong answer. Now I implemented the matrix and the results didn't converge.

I'm using a iteration counter in my code which prevents it from running more than 1000 times to a single timestep in the problem. For most timesteps, it converges in 2 or 3 iterations, but for some it goes through the 1000 iterations.

For four of the characteristics I switched from the matrices to using an equation to generate the values and it worked, but for the fifth I can't do that because there's no simple equation, so I really must get them from the matrix.

Since the data I'm using is huge (1GB), I can't import it with `numpy.loadtxt()`. So I'm importing it in the form of a list as follows:

```
ctot = []
with open('c_TOT.dat', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        ctot.append([float(x) for x in line.split(' ')])
```

Later, I'm calling the data with this line:

```
cp[i] = ctot[int(100*Ts[i])][int(1000*Hres[i])]
```

**The Problem**

Neither the temperatures (`Ts`) nor the magnetic fields (`Hres`) are integers, so I'm multiplying them by a power of 10 to get to the precision I need (like, 302.4123ºC must become 30241 and 0.93485T, 934, for me to get the value in line 30241, column 934, which represents the specific heat for these conditions).

I'm not sure why it's not converging and why only for some timesteps in the middle of the problem. I think it can't be the precision, since it's already too precise, but I also didn't find a way to test it.

If there's a better way to import the matrix or to call it, it would be good to know, because I think that's the problem.

Comment: Your question is very abstract and broad, you haven't provided a [mre], and we can't examine the data in the 1GB file — so it's difficult to help. That said, there's something called a [`numpy.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) that would likely make it possible for you to access the data in the huge file.

Comment: I'll try to use memmap to see if it works. I couldn't find a way to explain my problem better without getting overly complicated. Well, thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I recovered the results for the last 3 iterations before the divergence condition was met. It turns out the simplification made for the problem (getting the floor for the values, so the 302.4175ºC density was considered to be the 302.41ºC density) was really causing the divergence for some temperature values transition. In the case I recovered the results, the temperature was oscillating between 23.41996ºC and 23.42003ºC, so with a minimum change, there was a major change in properties.
Turned out to be calling just fine, but the physical simplification was invalid afterall.